# Log files with same content after build

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I performed Poky build fetching the latest master branch from git

```
git clone -b rocko git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
```

Set up the Environment using the following command

```
source poky/oe-init-build-env
```

Then executed bitbake command

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
```

Bitbake did generate root file system, kernel image .. I was looking at the log files of the bitbake in build/tmp/log/cooker/qemux86 folder

There are two files with the same content:

```
 - console-latest.log
 - 20171224045428.log
```

Why we have two logs of the same content

Comment: You can join #yocto channel on [freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/) if you have other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console-latest.log is a symlink that points to the latest real console file 20171224045428.log. It allows to keep previous console logs and have an easy single way to access the latest console log.

In Yocto, a lot of log files work this way, see [manual log section](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-viewing-logs-from-failed-tasks).